# Angular ng-show After Restangular API call

Tags: angularjs, restangular, ng-show

I am having trouble getting a ng-show to update after making a Restangular api call. I have tried using $appply after getting the response from the api but I get a '$digest already in progress' error.

```
Restangular.one("registrants/" + $scope.registrant.id).customPUT($scope.registrant, "").then(function (response) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.registrant = response.registrant;
        });
});
```

and in the view

```
<span ng-show="registrant.checked_in">User is checked in</span>

<span ng-hide="registrant.checked_in">User is not checked in</span>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Didi you find a fix for your example?

Answer (score 0):

I've made some simple changes that might solve your problem:

```
Restangular
  .one('registrants', $scope.registrant.id) // prepares base route /registrants/registrantId
  .customPUT($scope.registrant, '') // makes PUT on /registrants/registrantId with payload object $scope.registrant
  .then(function (response) {
    $scope.registrant = response.registrant;
  });
```

Make sure you check that the actual requests are made (network panel in chrome dev tools / firebug). Also, check that you really want to make a PUT rather than a PATCH:

```
Restangular
  .one('registrants', $scope.registrant.id) // prepares base route /registrants/registrantId
  .patch($scope.registrant) // makes PATCH on /registrants/registrantId with payload object $scope.registrant
  .then(function (response) {
    $scope.registrant = response.registrant;
  });
```

The $apply is not really needed since the callback is executed within a $rootScope.apply() whenever the XHR response is fully returned.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The api call is made and returned successfully with updated information. If I trace 'response.registrant.checked_in' I am able to see the updated value. I can also see the correct information returned from the api via Charles. The show/hide just doesn't update when I update $scope.registrant with the response.

Comment: Ok, I see. Try wrapping the contents of the then function inside a $timeout(). Even if time is set to zero it usually picks it up into a digest.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately a $timeout didn't work even when setting to 5 seconds.

Comment: Strange, I have used this with scope a hundred times and the binding has always been flawless. Is response.registrant holding the expected information?

Comment: Yup it has the expected information. Other fields update properly upon receiving the response like:
    <div>{{first_name}}</div>

Its just the hide/show of the spans.

Comment: Prob worth noting even after setting:
    $scope.registrant = response.registrant;
    console.log($scope.registrant.checked_in);//shows correct updated value

The UI just never updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can always work around the issue with:

```
<span>User is {{registrant.checked_in ? '' : 'not '}}checked in</span>
```

Or:

```
<span>User is <span ng-hide="registrant.checked_in">not</span> checked in</span>
```